# Run Mosquitto Broker on a specific EC2 Instance Sub Domain

Tags: amazon-ec2, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a Mosquitto Broker running on an EC2 Windows Instance. I can connect to it from localhost as well as from outside the EC2 instance using the IP/DNS/Name of the EC2 instance.

I have 3 sub domains connected to Public IP of my EC2 instance. These sub domains are:

- *api.mysite.com*
- *admin.mysite.com*
- *mqtt.mysite.com*

Currently, I can connect to my broker using any of the 3 sub domains as host and 1883 as port. I have a `listener 1883` in my `mosquitto.conf` file.

What I want is to only allow `mqtt.mysite.com` as a valid host for MQTT connection. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No. Assuming all the hostnames point to the same IP address then there is no way limit access.

Mosquitto can be configured to bind a listener to a specific local IP address, but not to a specific hostname.